Subject: Issue Creating Quarkus Project
I'm working with the Quarkus Framework and I've encountered an issue while trying to create a new project using the following command: enter image description here:
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create \ 
-DprojectGroupId=com.example \ 
-DprojectArtifactId=hello-quarkus \ 
-DprojectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \ 
-DclassName="com.example.HelloResource" \ 
-Dpath="/hello"

the error:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  22.443 s [INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-05T16:57:22+02:00 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create failed: Plugin io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-function:jar:2.3.0 (absent), io.quarkus:quarkus-project-core-extension-codestarts:jar:3.9.2 (absent), io.quarkus.qute:qute-core:jar:3.9.2 (absent): Could not transfer artifact io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-function:jar:2.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\common\smallrye-common-function\2.3.0\smallrye-common-function-2.3.0.jar.8375725404913469981.tmp: Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

I'm trying to create a quarkus project

You seem to have not added the entire error
